# GNU Parted library somehow disables partition opening

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, device

I used to open disk partitions using regular `open` call:

```
int fd = open("/dev/sdb1", O_RDWR);
```

However, when I have a number of Parted library calls in my source, the `open` call returns `No such file or directory` error, *even when these Parted functions aren't actually called*. For example, the code below:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <parted/parted.h>
#include <cerrno> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void find()
{
  PedDevice* pdev = ped_device_get("/dev/sdb");
}

void Out(const std::string& S, int R)
{
  std::cout << S << "\t" << R << "\t" << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int fd = open("/dev/sdb1", O_RDWR);
  Out("Opening  ", fd);
  int res = close(fd);
  Out("Closing  ", res);
}
```

outputs:

```
Opening     3   No such file or directory
Closing     0   No such file or directory
```

If just to comment the `ped_device_get` call out, then the program will output:

```
Opening     3   Success
Closing     0   Success
```

What's happening here?

(I'm on Ubuntu 3.11.0-15, which runs in VMware Fusion 6.0.2 on MacBook Pro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is really a StackOverflow answer.  But since I've voted for migration there …*

What's happening is that you've made a novice mistake:

> the `open` call returns `No such file or directory` error

No, it did not.  It returned the value 3, as you can easily see from the program output.  That does not signify an error.  Neither does the value 0 returned from `close()`.

Only check and use the value of the `errno` macro *if a function has indicated that it has set it*.  If `open()` had returned -1, indicating that it has set the value of `errno`, you could have legitimately interpreted the value of the macro as the error from the call.  But since it didn't, you cannot.

Put another way: These functions do not *reset* the value of the `errno` macro upon success.  They only *set* the value on failure.

The `ENOENT` error was from a previous failing system call somewhere.  `strace` will probably tell you where.  No doubt linking in that extra library causes initialization code to run before `main()`.

Comment: I'm still confused: how the code, which is not called (I mean the function `find()`), could affect the `errno` setting? I know about `errno`, but I'm new to the Parted library. My question was mostly about this library, and I suspect something really deep is going on here.

Comment: I skimmed the libparted source after writing that answer.  It does indeed have code that runs before `main()`, and that code is fairly easy to find.  I therefore leave doing so and seeing what system calls it makes as an exercise for the reader.  (-: